# openSSH - ECDSA key fingerprint

Tags: bash, openssh

Once in a while I get this question when I want to ssh to my linux.

```
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:...................................
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

Is it possible to disable this question?

Comment: Please add the full message (without the key fingerprint, of course) to you question. This question should be asked only once at the first connection, to verify that the remote system you are about to connect to actually is the one you intend to connect to. After you answered 'yes' the first time, the remote system's key should be added to your local `known_hosts` file, and you shouldn't be asked again. If you're asked repeatedly for the same remote system, this means that something changed - the remote key was renewed, the known key was removed from the `known_hosts` file or something else.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Add this information [to your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1423040/edit).

Comment: This will happen with Ubuntu 16.04, 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04.

Comment: Sure, after 2nd login this question disappears, but after a while it comes back again. In my case the remote key probably has changed. This leads to next question. Why and how often does this key change. Is this configurable?